# How to find and replace by reading xml node value?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

Following is my XML value.

```
<Components>
    <Component>
        <FullName>CoreEnvironment</FullName>
        <ShortName>CoreEnv</ShortName>
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <FullName>Excel Addin 2007</FullName>
        <ShortName>Excel_07</ShortName>
    </Component>
</Components>
```

If user pass Full Name of a component then corresponding short name should be displayed. I am able to read a particular node in xml using powershell. But in this case if one FullName node is found then corresponding shortname node should be displayed. I am unable to figure out the logic for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[xml]$xml="<Components>
    <Component>
        <FullName>CoreEnvironment</FullName>
        <ShortName>CoreEnv</ShortName>
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <FullName>Excel Addin 2007</FullName>
        <ShortName>Excel_07</ShortName>
    </Component>
</Components>"

$test="Excel Addin 2007"

$xml.Components.Component |% { if( $_.fullname -match $test) { write-host  $_.ShortName}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kayasax's answer but using XPath

```
[xml] $xml = "<Components>
    <Component>
        <FullName>CoreEnvironment</FullName>
        <ShortName>CoreEnv</ShortName>
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <FullName>Excel Addin 2007</FullName>
        <ShortName>Excel_07</ShortName>
    </Component>
</Components>"

$param = "Excel Addin 2007"

$xml.SelectNodes('//Component') | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq "$param" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ShortName
```